# Is this an accurate calculation of paskha bala in vedic astrology?

Tags: astrology

**Code**

```
const moonLong = 3;
const sunLong = 2;
const isMoonLower = moonLong < sunLong;

const dif = isMoonLower ? 360 + moonLong - sunLong : moonLong - sunLong;

const beneficsPakshabala = dif > 180 ? (360 - dif) / 3 : dif / 3;
const maleficPakshabala = 60 - beneficsPakshabala;

// 12 degrees is a day. 180 is exact opposite full  moon, and within 6 degrees either side is full moon
const isMoonShukla = dif >= 174 && dif <= 186;
const isMoonKrishna = dif >= 354 || dif <= 6;
const isMoonShuklaOrKrishna = isMoonShukla || isMoonKrishna;
const multiplyMoonShuklaOrKrishna = isMoonShuklaOrKrishna ? 2: 1;

// 7.5 days to new moon, or 7.5 days just after the new moon.
const isMoonDark = dif < 90 || dif > 270; 
const moonPakshabala = isMoonDark ? maleficPakshabala * multiplyMoonShuklaOrKrishna : beneficsPakshabala * multiplyMoonShuklaOrKrishna;

console.log( {dif, isMoonDark, isMoonShuklaOrKrishna, beneficsPakshabala, maleficPakshabala, moonPakshabala})
```

## Examples of longitudes to shastiamsa

1. **Moon:0, Sun: 0**

- beneficsPakshabala = 0 shastiamsa;
- maleficPakshabala = 60 shastiamsa;
- moonPakshabala =   120 shastiamsa;

2. **Moon:60, Sun: 0**

- beneficsPakshabala = 20 shastiamsa;
- maleficPakshabala = 40 shastiamsa;
- moonPakshabala =   40 shastiamsa;

3. **Moon:120, Sun: 0**

- beneficsPakshabala = 40 shastiamsa;
- maleficPakshabala = 20 shastiamsa;
- moonPakshabala =   40 shastiamsa;

3. **Moon:180, Sun: 0**

- beneficsPakshabala = 60 shastiamsa;
- maleficPakshabala = 20 shastiamsa;
- moonPakshabala =   120 shastiamsa;